# Javascript async/await behaviour explanation

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I always thought that Javascipt's async/await is just sugar syntax, e.g. writing this peace of code

```
let asyncVar = await AsyncFunc()
console.log(asyncVar)
//rest of code with asyncVar
```

is equivalent to writing this

```
AsyncFunc().then(asyncVar => {
   console.log(asyncVar)
   //rest of the code with asyncVar
})
```

Especially since you can call await on some random, non-promise object and it will try to call it's then() function

However, I tried this peace of code

```
let asyncFunc = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       setTimeout(_ => resolve('This is async'), 1000)
    })
}

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log('This is sync')
   asyncFunc().then(val => console.log(val))
}
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log('This is sync')
   console.log(await asyncFunc())
}
```

First loop outputs 'This is sync' 5 times, and then 'This is async' 5 times, as expected.
Second loop outputs 'This is sync', 'This is async', 'This is sync', 'This is async' and so on.

Can someone explain what is the difference, or in other words, what exactly async/await does behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two examples are basically equivalent.  But, guess what, you can't use a `for` loop in those two examples.  There isn't a simple-to-code way to mimic an `await` statement inside a `for` loop.  That's because the interaction of a `for` loop (or a `while` loop) with `async/await` is more advanced than plugging in a simple `.then()` statement as in your two examples.

`await` pauses the execution of the entire containing function.  This will pause even `for` and `while` loops.  To program something similarly with only `.then()`, you have to invent your own looping construct because you can't do it with just a `for` loop.

For example, if you have this using `await`:

```
let asyncFunc = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       setTimeout(_ => resolve('This is async'), 1000)
    })
}

async function someFunc() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       console.log('This is sync')
       console.log(await asyncFunc())
    }
}
```

And, if you want an analogy using only `.then()`, you can't use the `for` loop because there's no way to "pause" it without `await`.  Instead, you have to devise your own loop which usually involves calling a local function and maintaining your own counter:

```
function someFunc() {
    let i = 0;

    function run() {
        if (i++ < 5) {
            console.log('This is sync')
            asyncFunc().then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                run();
            });
        }
    }
    run();
}
```

Or, some use a `.reduce()` construct such as this (particularly if you're iterating an array):

```
// sequence async calls iterating an array
function someFunc() {
    let data = [1,2,3,4,5];
    return data.reduce((p, val) => {
        console.log('This is sync')
        return p.then(() => {
           return asyncFunc().then(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

> Can someone explain what is the difference, or in other words, what exactly async/await does behind the scenes?

Behind the scenes, the Javascript interpreter suspends further execution of a function at an await statement.  That current function context (local variable state, point of execution, etc...) is saved, a promise is returned from the function and execution outside that function continues until sometime later when the promise that was being await ed resolved or rejects.  If it resolves, then that same execution state is picked up and the function continues to execute some more until the next `await` and so on until eventually the function has no more `await` statements and has no more to execute (or gets to a `return` statement).

To explain further, here's some background on an async function:

When you declare an `async` function, the interpreter creates a special kind of function that always returns a promise.  That promise is rejected if the function either explicitly returns a rejected promise or if there's an exception in the function (the exception is caught by the interpreter and changed into a rejection for the promise that the function returns).

The promise is resolved if/when the function returns a normal value or just returns normally by finishing its execution.

When you call the function, it starts out executing synchronously just like any normal function.  This includes any loops that might be in the function (as in the `for` loop in your example).  As soon as the function encounters the first `await` statement and the value it's awaiting is a promise, then the function returns at that point and returns its promise.  Further execution of that function is suspended.  Since the function returns its promise, any code after that function call continues to run.  Sometime later when the promise that was being awaited internal to the `async` function resolves, an event is inserted into the event loop to resume execution of that function.  When the interpreter gets back to the event loop and gets to that event, then execution of the function is resumed where it previous left off on the line right after the `await` statement.

If there are any other `await` statements that are awaiting promises, then they will similarly cause the function execution to be suspended until the promise that is being awaited is resolved or rejected.

The beauty of this ability to suspend or pause execution of a function in mid-course is that it works in loop constructs such as `for` and `while` and that makes executing async operations in sequence using such a loop a ton easier to program that before we had `async` and `await` (as you've discovered).  There is no simply analagous way to code a sequencing loop using only `.then()`.  Some use `.reduce()` as shown above.  Others use the internal function call as also shown above.

Comment: Thank you for this very descriptive answer. This answer is similar to one answer before, but to clarify, you are saying that async/await is not just a syntatic sugar and it actually pauses execution of the function? I know it does not really make difference, and it depends on interpreter, but just out of curiosity (focusing on node.js)

Comment: @IvanJakab - Yes, it actually pauses execution of the function.  To the outside world, the function returns a promise at the point of the first `await`.  Internal to the function, execution is paused and will resume later when the awaited promise resolves.  `async/await` is more than syntactic sugar. It allows you to do some things more easily than you can do with `.then()` as my code examples show.  `await` does NOT block the interpreter or the event loop.  The outside world (outside the `async` function) thinks the function returned an unresolved promise (because it did).

Answer (score 1):

async/await is a next generation of promises. Basically, await will hold the execution of rest of the code, till await resolve.
Eg.

```
async function getUser() {    
     const id = 'zzzz';    
     const user = await get(`http://getuser.xxx/{id}`);

     console.log(user);    
}
```

The only console get printed after get function executes.

Answer (score 1):

`await` does what it says on the box: it awaits the response of your asynchronous function:

```
let asyncFunc = () =>
    new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => resolve("This is async"), 5000)
    });

console.log("before await");
console.log(await asyncFunc());
console.log("after await");
```

This will log `"before await"`, then, after 5 seconds, it will log `"This is async"`, followed by `"after await"`.

It basically makes the asynchronous function behave synchronously.

Comment: I know it behaves that way, but this does not answer my question unfortunately

Comment: @IvanJakab: then what exactly is your question? How it's implemented?

Answer (score 0):

In isolation, yes `async/await` are syntax sugar for promises. You are missing the bigger context: promises themselves are there because JS couldn't pause execution of a function before `await` came to be. In order to simulate this pausing effect, you have to transform the whole synchronous function (in this case, the `for` loop), not just the `await` line.

First, we have to unroll the `for` loop into a `while` (speaking of syntactic sugar!), then we can rewrite it into recursion (because pre-`await` we can only "stop" between functions, not inside them), then we can rewire it to recurse only on promise fulfillment. This is your code when transformed from `async/await` into promises:

```js
let asyncFunc = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('This is async'), 1000)
  });
};

function loop(i) {
  if (i < 5) {
    console.log('This is sync');
    return asyncFunc().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return loop(++i);
    });
  }
}

loop(0);
```

You basically now have two kinds of functions: `async` ones and non-`async` ones, and only `async` functions can have `await` in them (or you'll get "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"). This is kind of the reason: in order to "rewrite" the `await` semantics into the non-`await` one, you need to change the entire function, not just the `await` lines. It is a syntactic sugar, but on a *whole function* level, not at a statement level as in OP examples.

EDIT: You can also basically read off what needs be done in your original code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   console.log('This is sync')
   console.log(await asyncFunc())
}
```

> Let a loop start with `i` being `0`. Check that `i` is less then `5`; if so, log "This is sync", and invoke `asyncFunc` (and wait for it to finish). *Then*, print out its result, increment the counter and continue the loop.

Despite the code being rather drastically rearranged with respect to JavaScript syntax, it still sounds very much like what I wrote, no? :)

Comment: This actually explains a lot, but are you saying that for loops are actually recursive functions behind the scenes? That would explain a lot, since I did read somewhere that for(let i = 0; i<5;i++) actually creates new lexical context for variable i on every iteration and copies previous value to it

Comment: @IvanJakab: what they are behind the scenes completely depends on how the browser / engine implements them.

Comment: No, behind the scenes they are likely not recursive functions. I wrote that to illustrate what kind of code `async/await` was created to replace, given that syntactic extension was made. The only way to know exactly what actually happens behind the scenes is to read the browser source code. The only way to have a rather clear idea what is _supposed to_ happen is to read the ECMAScript specification (starting [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-definitions) and [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-function-objects)).

Comment: You seem to be under a misapprehension that people using the phrase "syntactic sugar" just means it is a simple search&replace from promise code. It is not. As should be clear from my example, `async/await` impact heavily the structure of the code, and it is rather mistaken to regard one as a macro for the other. However, as you can see, it is always possible to write the same thing in promise style and in async/await style, and the latter is clearly easier to read - this is why people call it "syntactic sugar", since you can rewrite the same semantics in a much easier to swallow syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` may be syntactic sugar, but it's more than just sugar around `then()` A much better analogy for `async/await` is **generators + promises.**  If you write a generator you will notice that the syntax is almost the same as `async/await` but using `yield` instead of await.

For example you can write a generator that look almost exactly like your second `for` loop and it will give you the same behavior:

```js
let asyncFunc = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     setTimeout(_ => resolve('This is async'), 1000)
  })
}

/*  Generator Function  */
function *gen(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('This is sync')
    yield asyncFunc().then(console.log)  // looks and acts a lot like await
   }
}

/* iterate through the generator */
let it = gen()
function runGen(){
  let p = it.next()
  if (p.done) return
  else p.value.then(runGen)
}
runGen()
```

Comment: But it does @Cerbrus. `await` works very much like `yield` in generators. It pauses the execution at that point in the function -- just like yield. The syntax looks the same; the behavior is very close to the same. The question is asking "what's going on behind the scenes" and trying to understand it in terms of syntactic sugar. I thought this might be helpful…clearly not everyone thinks so.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to get at, is that for someone that doesn't know how await works, generators might be even more obscure. I don't think you _simplified_ the code ;-)

Comment: We clearly read the question differently @Cerbrus. It looks like the OP knows how to use `async/await` just fine to me.

Comment: How to _use_ it, yes. But he's explicitly asking how it _works_, _"what exactly async/await does behind the scenes?"_ All I was saying was that generators might be even more confusing if you're trying to explain what `await` does.

Comment: I understand your point @Cerbrus. But if I ask how `await` works & the answer is "await awaits the response", that tells me nothing. It gives zero insight into "what exactly async/await does behind the scenes?".  If I ask about what syntax is being sugared, then I'm looking  for something more than "await awaits the response". And the answer 'it makes the asynchronous function behave synchronously', well…that's actually wrong. It makes them behave like generators, which is my point. They pause in a way synchronous functions *can't.* So,  I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt on this one.

Comment: generators and yield are likely less well understood by most than async/await so using yield and generators to explain async/await is not going to help very many people.  It's kind of like explaining the meaning of a Spanish phrase to an English speaker by using French words.

Comment: I will have to side with @MarkMeyer in this one, this answer is very descriptive and explains a lot. Maybe I did not make myself clear but I wanted to find out what is async/await syntactic for, and I don't see how I indicated that I would not be able to understand generator explanation. Thank you for your answe, I got some bad ones, although there is one good answer, that is either not quite the same or that one actually explains how yield works behind the scenes

Comment: syntactic sugar* for, answer*, did not notice it on the time

Comment: Thank @IvanJakab.